# iOS Best Practice Dev vs Production

Tags: ios, xcode, sdk

I want to figure out best practices for the following.  Majority of the SDK's and API's I use offer me two APP ID's.  One for live and one for testing.  What is the best way to set this up so that I simply have to change one variable and the app knows the proper APP ID's to load.  Example;

Example

```
// When app is live 
kFACEBOOK_APP_ID = @"12345_live";

// When app is in development
kFACEBOOK_APP_ID = @"12345_dev";

APP_LIVE = TRUE;

[FBSettings setDefaultAppID:kFACEBOOK_APP_ID];
```

This should send @"12345_live";

Comment: I should clarify - outside of using an if statement to compare development state, is there a built in way with iOS to handle this or do we have to make our own way / are there any frameworks that handle it for us

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with some basic programming fundamentals.

Treat the following code as pseudocode:

```
APP_LIVE = true;

if (APP_LIVE) {
  // Application is in LIVE mode
  kFACEBOOK_APP_ID = @"12345_live";
  kOTHER_APP_ID = @"43124312_live";
} else {
  // Application is in DEV mode
  kFACEBOOK_APP_ID = @"12345_dev";
  kOTHER_APP_ID = @"43124312_dev";
}

// Regardless of Application state LIVE/DEV, appropriate ID is now entered
[FBSettings setDefaultAppID:kFACEBOOK_APP_ID];
```

This code can be used in place of where you are currently running your [FBSettings setDefaultAppID:] function call.